# Pandas: Merging/Organizing Tables into a new table

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merge

What is the best way to merge/consolidate multiple tables in pandas?  For simplicity, lets say we have 3 simple tables as a dataframe like so:

Table1

```
AA_max    55
AA_min    40
BB_max    23
BB_min    10
```

Table2

```
AA_max    55
AA_min    40
```

Table3

```
AA_max    85
AA_min    10
BB_max    23
BB_min    10
```

How would you generate a consolidated table like so:

```
Item | Table1 min | Table1 max | Table2 min | Table2 max | Table3 min | Table3 max
AA     40           55           40           55           10           85          
BB     10           23                                     10           23
```

Is it doable using pandas?  If not, is it better to just iterate each of the rows per table, insert to a dictionary and populate the columns accordingly as you iterate them?

Assume an item from another table may or may not exist from the other tables.

Comment: What is the index and column name of given tables?

Comment: Assume index is just incrementing numbers (which will be ignored) -- since other tables may not have some of the items.  These index numbers cannot be used to map a specific item to another table.  The original column names are just 'name' and 'value'?  Doesnt matter really since those column names will not be in the result table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

- `Concat` the tables along column axis
- `Split` the index in order to convert to multiindex
- `Unstack` on level=1 to reshape
- Flatten the multilevel columns using `map` and `join`

```
tables = [df1, df2, df3]
out = pd.concat({f'Table_{i}': df.set_index('name')['val'] 
                 for i, df in enumerate(tables, 1)}, axis=1)

out.index = out.index.str.split('_', expand=True)
out = out.unstack()
out.columns = out.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Result

```
print(out)

    Table_1_max  Table_1_min  Table_2_max  Table_2_min  Table_3_max  Table_3_min
AA           55           40         55.0         40.0           85           10
BB           23           10          NaN          NaN           23           10
```